# Ember + django @ How to send List of objects via ajax to backend?

Tags: django, ember.js

I am using python&Django REST for backend.

How to send List format to the bakend via ajax

Any sort of help should be appreciable

EMBER

```
var data_payload = [{"title":"ember", "title":"ember-cli"}]

return ajax({
    url: 'here django server url',
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(data_payload)
   }).then(function(output) {
       return output;
   });
```

DJANGO REST Framework:

I am getting wrong format as below

```
{u'[{"title":"ember"},{"tile":"ember-cli"}]': u''}
```

The correct format should be like

```
[{"title":"ember"},{"tile":"ember-cli"}]
```

Comment: if you aren't using ember-data you could fetch the data from DRF using any $.ajax setup you can craft yourself. Is ember-data an implicit requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
ajax({
    url: 'here django server url',
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify({data: data_payload}),
    traditional: true,
}).then(function(output) {
   return output;
});
```

Comment: no luck, getting the same format..
{u'{"data":[{"title":"ember"},{"tile":"ember-cli"}]}': u''}

Comment: you have to parse the response on your server side

Comment: No..i am using django rest framework..I should get the same format otherwise no meaning for rest api calls

Comment: so don't send the data using JSON.stringify({data: data_payload}) use 
data: {data: data_payload}
that will do it

Comment: I almost tried every possibility. I am still not understanding why its not working. If I remove json.stringify then am i getting the same sort of output {u'data': u'[object Object]'}

Comment: Its simply print statement i.e.
print request.data

Comment: try this request.DATA.get('data'')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87879/discussion-between-muhammad-shoaib-and-user2224250).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help !!

Just now problem has been resolved. The problem is with ajax function.